# htaccess is not properly working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Iam trying to redirect the url

mysiteurl/489b2af630dda933d521088d0/Salman%20Khan

to

mysiteurl/showImage.php?ik=489b2af630dda933d521088d0.

1) Please help me to write the htaccess code

2) Is there any way to  use the url as mysiteurl/Salman%20Khan. I mean I would like to hide the image key in the url .

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the **bolded** string to your .htaccess file

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+|**(*.css)**$ showImage.php?ik=$1&title=$2